# не отображается background image в css

Tags: css, reactjs, веб-программирование, изображения, background-image

Хотя панель разработчика видит картинку, и в целом css подключен правильно (это можно проверить тем, что остальные изменения применяются на кнопке), фоновая картинка все равно не отображается. Какая может быть причина?

css:

```
.header__menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  background-image: url(../../../images/menu.png);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[image: место где должна быть картинка][image: в панели разработчика]

Comment: Я думаю вам данные линии лучше реализовать с помощью `css` или же `svg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

размер картинки был слишком большим.

```
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

решил вопрос)